# Asset Management for Software Components

Tags: saas, digital-asset-management, asset-management

SAM (Software Asset Management) providers I know (e.g. Blissfully, Zylo, Snow) focus on software used internally in a company (e.g. Slack, Dropbox). I'm looking for a Software / SaaS Asset Management platform with a focus on user-facing software components that we integrate into our products (e.g. UI widgets, chatbots, messaging system, monitoring, authentication, other microservices). I want to use it for budgeting, license management, compliance, etc.

Talked to Blissfully and Zylo but they don't offer this and they believe other SAM providers don't either.

I know of the startup [componently.com](https://www.componently.com/) but I'm wondering if there're any long-standing companies in this space.

*There're a few questions on this board around SAM but I'm specifically looking for a solution for software components.*